# jQuery toggle select from select option mechanism

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, jquery-events

I am trying to toggle via a select option. I am having difficulties toggling more than two. My goal is to be able toggle as far as 4 through the select option. For example Categories and subcategories. Here is my example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uA7XD/64).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var op = $("#tables option[value='options']:selected");
    var os = $("#tables option[value='Example2']:selected");
    if (op.length)
        $("#something").show();
    else
        $("#something").hide();
    if (op == ("#something").show())
             $("#something2").show();
    else
        $("#something2").hide();

}​
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the design pattern you are looking for?

```
if your object is not selected
    if your parent is selected
        you are also selected
    else
        you are selected
else
    you are now unselected
```

This logic will work for any depth of recursion.

EDIT: Assuming each menu is a ul. You'll have to tweak the selectors.
This is just one way to do it. Not the best if you have events firing on visibility, or if you have ui reflow issues.

```
clickyclicky = function(event) {
    var $target = $(event.currentTarget);
    if (!$target.hasClass("selected")) {
        // hide the old target and its parents
        var $oldTarget = $('.selected');
        $oldTarget.removeClass("selected").hide().parents('ul').hide();
        // show the new target and its parents
        $target.show().addClass("selected").parents('ul').show();
    } else {
        // hide the target
        $target.removeClass("selected").hide();
        // move the selected token to the parent.
        $parent = $target.parent().parent(); // assuming an ul/li tree pattern.
        if ($parent.is('ul')) {
            $parent.addClass("selected");
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code, it's just a general reference.

EDIT: Here's the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uA7XD/76/

Comment: Thank you. I read the comments left in your code. Could you help me plug the javascript into this live example: ---> [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uA7XD/67/).

Comment: I have provided the ul/li version in your JSFiddle. I personally like how the single :hover style annotates your path. Please feel free to play with the HTML. Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you! for your kindness and help. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: I dont mean to be bothersome. Beautiful work but  as you mentioned the example works with a list. I played around and tried to change it to select boxes but no luck. One last request: How can i get this to work with select boxes properly?

Comment: May I ask why you are wanting to do this with a select box? You could just as easily style the ul/li to look the exact same. Give the css a little love and let me know if there is any functionality missing.